# react native request with axios

Tags: node.js, react-native, asynchronous, axios, genymotion

I'm trying make a axios request to my nodeJS back-end API.
I'm using Genymotion with request setting ass follow:

```
async componentDidMount() {
            const response = await axios.get('http://10.0.3.2:3333/posts');

            console.log(response)
    }
```

I'm getting this as response:
[image: Request response]

but I expected get the real data like when I make a get request in my browser:
[image]

So I'm getting problem only with request fron other domain

the data string:
[image]

this is mais entry point controller:

```
Routes.js
routes.get('/posts', postController.index);
```

postController.index

```
async index(req, res) {
        console.log(req)
        const post = await Post.find().sort('-createdAt')
        return res.json(post)
    }
```

The request don't arrive on the console.log

Comment: Could you add the method from your backend that returns the data?

Comment: I've edit the question

Comment: Are you sure you're making the right call  `const response = await axios.get('http://10.0.3.2:3333/posts');`? In your browser you got `http://localhost:3333/posts`

Comment: Oh you're using Genymotion, just make sure the host is correct, try accessing the `http://10.0.3.2:3333/posts` in your browser maybe?

Comment: Genymotion dont use the localhost for connetion

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this using my own IP adress, I copied my IPV6 adress and used it as adress to make te request.